# dependencies necessary for Bootstrap's carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dependencies, bootstrap-5

What JavaScript dependencies needs to be included when I want to use just the Carousel functionality? That means I don't want to use `bootstrap.js`, just `JS` necessary for Carousel (`carousel.js`, ...).

The setup code (with regards to the docs) is:

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel)
```

But obviously the `Bootstrap 5` part is missing, as I get the error:

```
(index):511 Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
```

I can't seem to find this info in Bootstrap's official docs and anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I does not give the error if you include bootstrap bundle for instance.

So you must not have included popper or jquery or bootstrap(.min).js

with:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```js
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#myCarousel')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. yes I did not include the bootstrap.js or bootstrap.bundle.js. jQuery is not a part of v5. As mentioned I want to include only minimum JS code. That is carousel.js and now I am looking for minimum dependency required. I guess when I include bootstrap.js, or bootstrap.bundle.js (not sure which of them contains what), it will contain also all other codes (alert.js, modal.js ...) which I don't need.